# Only coverage for test classes in opencover

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

I have a problem to get the coverage from my classes with opencover.

I have a Viewer.dll with the main classes and a Viewer_Test.dll with the tests for the viewer.

After executing the commands all tests run as expected.

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"$(nunitpath)/nunit-console-x86.exe" -targetargs:"/noshadow Viewer_Tests.dll /domain:single" -filter:+[*]* -output:coverage.xml

ReportGenerator.exe coverage.xml "coveragereport" html
```

If I look in the generated report I find only the test classes listed, not the main classes.

Here is the console output of the opencover command.

```
Committing...
Visited Classes 5 of 5 (100)
Visited Methods 41 of 41 (100)
Visited Points 482 of 557 (86.5350089766607)
Visited Branches 6 of 12 (50)

==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====
Alternative Visited Classes 5 of 5 (100)
Alternative Visited Methods 44 of 44 (100)
```

How can I make opencover to cover the Viewer.dll too?

Comment: In the XML that opencover produces - it lists all the classes/modules it encountered and reasons why it skipped them. Does it notice the Viewer.dll module and if so what does it say?

Comment: I've checked the coverage.xml and it lists the Viewer.dll but skipped it due to missing pdb. But the Viewer.pdb exists in the same directory.

Comment: Very odd - Raise the issue with OpenCover with a repeatable sample.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem?