# Coverage report using opencover

Tags: opencover, reportgenerator

Well I am using opencover to generate the coverage report for the cpp code in html format. The report produced by the open cover seems to be like the amount of code covered by each test method as said in [this](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/11/7/reportgenerator-new-release-with-coverage-by-test-support) post.

**First screenshot:**

[image: Coverage Report]

**Second screenshot:**

[image: Report].

As seen in the second screenshot the coverage report is shown for the test project `calctest.cpp` but I want coverage report for the actual source file `calc.cpp` which is included in its header.

What I wanna to be shown is like as seen in `calctest.cpp`there two methods sum and mul in the `calc.cpp` and this two methods should be displayed in the first screenshot instead of the testmethod1, testmethod2,etc.

I think I made it clear or am I understanding incorrectly.

**EDIT:**

I think I am facing the same issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272914/only-coverage-for-test-classes-in-opencover?rq=1)

**UPDATE:**

As said by Shaun Wilde in the link mentioned in the edit, on checking the .xml generated by opencover I couldn't find my source project name i.e `CalcProject.lib` in it, it only has the test project by name `CalcTest.dll`. And there are certain module tag with following statements

```
<Module skippedDueTo="Filter" hash="E9-A8-6A-CC-31-FF-25-91-E6-86-F2-D5-72-EE-77-7D-AB-36-F0-0B">
<FullName>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll</FullName>
<ModuleName>mscorlib</ModuleName>
<Classes />
</Module>
```

The full .xml output cab be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2hJ2anL4)

Comment: Do you pass any filters to OpenCover? Can you provide the source code of a sample project?

Comment: No filters bro! The source code is [here](http://pastebin.com/pZ2KLLrh)

Comment: Is it possible to provide the full project. Otherwise I have to recreate it from scratch.

Comment: Dropbox, or drive.google.com?

Comment: Shared in [drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-dj4WrB8pKV1o3djAyMENkZ0k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: OpenCover requires that the corresponding PDB file is available. But CalcProject.pdb is not available. Can you configure the projects in a way that PDB is generated?

Comment: Yeah I made the changes to make the CalcProject.pdb available in the same directory as CalcProject.lib, but same problem continues!

Comment: Then I don't know. Perhaps you could open an issue here: https://github.com/opencover/opencover. Don't forget to supply the current project. That makes is easier to investigate.

Comment: I wonder if this is a issue wouldn't others have faced the same or am I missing anything? Anyways I will do that. Thank you!!!